# Responsive CSS - Two set sizes?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm hoping someone could shed some light on how I would do this in jQuery, css etc..

I have a website with the width of 900 pixels. But if the user expands there window with a width of 1140 pixels or more, I would like the website to have a set the width 1440 pixels. Nothing in between, reason for this is because I am using the jQuery quicksand plugin and I would like everything to fit perfectly.

Comment: Let me see if I get this, your site content should be 900px wide up until 1140px where the content should be 1440px (wider than the screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use media queries, you can [find info here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries). They are pretty rad.

Comment: This is definitely the better way to go about this, so long as you are developing for browsers that are compatible with CSS3.

Answer (score 2):

Media Queries are indeed the way to go; With no links or code samples, something like this should get you started, in your css:

```
#someSelector {width:900px;}//all the css here for less than 1140px

@media all and (min-width:1139px) {//css here for 1140 and up
    #someSelector {width:1140px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do this with jQuery and CSS, you could try the following (which is incredibly simple and not the best way to do it but meets your requests)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() >= '1440'){
      $("#wrapper").css('width','1440px');
    } else {
      $("#wrapper").css('width','900px');
    }
  });
});
```

*Alternatively, you could also try this which will make it easier to change other aspects of the layout by nesting your css:*

**CSS**

```
#wrapper_small { width: 900px; }
#wrapper_large { width: 1440px; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() >= '1440'){
      $("#wrapper_small").attr('id','wrapper_large');
    } else {
      $("#wrapper_large").attr('id','wrapper_small');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create a media query by putting something like this in your css:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1400px;) 

{
   #div {
   max-width:1440px;
   width:100%;
   }
}
```